# Have to use a thread sleep procedure to get document updated

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Word macro that needs to run using Java. So I use a VB script to
run the macro as below. It does some editing in the Word document and I use 
that "test.doc" to read as an `InputStream`. But I have to sleep the main 
thread for a while to get the document changes in the "test.doc" file (varies
the time needed to thread sleep time from document to document). As 
shown in code. I am a bit confused because I wait for the process to end.
And still the document is not updated?
Can someone please help me here?

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\test.vbs");
proc.waitFor();
Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
InputStream uploadedFileStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\test.doc"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of "start", so the created instance of Word doesn't run in the background, and the sleep which is now unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The above willspawn off the application for `test.vbs` in the *background*. So unfortunately it's not going to wait for Word at all.

I would either spawn Word *directly*, or record the modification time of `test.doc` and watch for that changing (by sleeping and checking every few seconds). The latter is not a particularly good approach, btw.

Comment: what is the advantage of spawning word directly? Do you have a java code?

Comment: @rana123 `The above willspawn off the application for test.vbs in the background. So unfortunately it's not going to wait for Word at all.`